# Defining a measure on a group from a measure on the equivalence classes

Tags: group-theory, measure-theory, equivalence-relations

Let $G$ be a group, and a $H$ a subgroup, and for $a,b \in G$ let $a\sim b$ if $aH = bH$. Suppose I have a measure $\mu$ on $G/\sim$, the left cosets of $H$, and suppose that $G$ is equipped with a sigma algebra $\Sigma_G$ that is closed under right multiplication by $H$ and whose projection is contained in the sigma algebra of $G/\sim$. How can I define a measure $\nu$ on $G$ that satisfies
$$\nu(AH) = \mu(\pi_\sim(A)),\qquad A \in \Sigma_G,$$
where $\pi_\sim : G \to G/\sim$ is the projection map and $AH = \{ ah : a\in A, h\in H \}$?

---

In my application, $G = SO(d)$ and $H = \{h\in G : hv=v\}$ for some fixed $v\in S^{d-1}$. The left cosets of $H$ are isomorphic to $S^{d-1}$, on which $\mu$ is defined.

Comment: You need more assumptions on your sigma-algebra, you should assume that it's projection to $G/H$ is contained in the sigma-algebra of $\mu$.

Comment: I think it's possible at least if there's a measurable set of coset representatives $S$ (then you can take $\nu(B) = \mu(\pi(B \cap S))$). But that's kind of a trivial, badly behaved answer with no nice compatibility properties. Would you like some sort of $G$-invariance?

Comment: Thanks for this. I was thinking of something along these lines. I am interested in integrating over $G = SO(d)$ with respect to this measure. Can I be sure that this set of coset representatives is measurable with respect to the Borel sigma algebra of $SO(d)$?

Comment: In your case I think there will be a Borel set of coset representatives. It comes down to showing "there is a Borel set $S$ of orthogonal matrices such that for each $x \in S^{d - 1}$, there is exactly one matrix in $S$ whose first column is $x$". This is fiddly (related to "hairy ball theorem"-type obstacles), but true, I think. The best argument I can come up with off the top of my head is by inducting on $d$ and making use of the continuity of the Gram-Schmidt process. I have no idea if the measure this produces will be useful to integrate over though!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen I don't think the hairy ball theorem is a problem, since it's about continuous maps and what you want is only a Borel map. I think the real problem with your suggestion is that $S$ is likely to have measure zero, in which case the measure $\nu$ will be identically zero.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, I'm far from an expert in this sort of stuff - sorry if I said something silly. I didn't mean that the hairy ball theorem actually stops anything from being true, it just makes life difficult (since it means you can't just argue by coming up with a clever continuous map). I'm sure there's an easier way to see it's Borel than what I said though! I don't understand why $\nu$ would be identically zero - for example $\nu(G) = \mu(\pi(S)) = \mu(G/H)$, right? $\nu$ is silly though, as I said, since it is identically zero on $G \setminus S$, which may very well look like "most of $G$".

Comment: (If you are doing the reasonable quotient thing...) can't you define an _integral_ by right-averaging over $H$, and then invoke Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem that produces a corresponding _measure_?

Comment: The point of my comment was really to provide an example of a trivial silly solution because I assume that it's not really what OP is looking for, so it might help with clarifying the question. I wrote it before I saw that OP was thinking about a specific group!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen You're right; $\nu$ isn't identically zero, but it's concentrated on $S$. It's essentially the given measure $\mu$ transferred to $S$ via $\pi$.